# What do you call it when a person labels something as its opposite so that discussion becomes impossible?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, fake news. When I hear it, I don’t know if the person is identifying the news as false or if they are proclaiming allegiance to Trump by labeling anything that has ever been critical of him fake.

Likewise, if I use the term, I don’t know if the people hearing me think I am making a considered judgment or if they think I’m declaring a political identification.

It makes discussion of “news” and “true” and “fake” impossible.

It has elements of “gaslighting,” but not the aspect of causing people to question their sanity.

It has elements of projection, but has the additional element of confusing discourse.

It has elements of a contronym or auto-antonym, but those don’t carry the threat to communication that these do.

---

These are all helpful in trying to pin down what works.  I still can't latch onto a word that captures all the dimensions.  Maybe what comes closer is that it's a form of doublethink -- Orwellian in its impact.

Comment: Exaggerating in an argument or using the big lie are forms of raising the stakes.

Comment: I don't think that calling something its "opposite" is exactly the tactic exemplified by the term "fake news." One could argue that the opposite of news is "old", not "fake." What is being done is negation, calling something unreal. Calling anything "fake" does negate debate, because it calls the thing itself a lie.

Comment: I think fake news is just an example: calling real news "fake news", or calling fake news "real news", are both cases where you're essentially arguing black is white. ("Arguing that black is white" is a commonish way of expressing this tactic but isn't very succinct.)

Comment: I don't think there's a specific word for this, it's just a form of obfuscation, or bullshit.

Answer (score 0):

Sophistry:
the use of fallacious arguments, especially with the intention of deceiving:
"trying to argue that I had benefited in any way from the disaster was pure sophistry"

synonyms:
trickery · deviousness · deceit · deception · dishonesty · cheating · duplicity · guile · cunning · artfulness · wiliness · craft · craftiness · evasion · slyness · [more]
a fallacious argument.
synonyms:
specious reasoning · the use of fallacious arguments · sophism · casuistry · quibbling · equivocation · fallaciousness · fallacious argument · fallacy · quibble · paralogism

Comment: These are all hypernyms, Easy, but have all been given before to questions asking for words covering 'the use of fallacious arguments, especially with the intention of deceiving'.